# How to switch views with routing inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngroute, ng-view

While learning Angular I have implemented Ember.js email widget from their home page (it is not displayed in plunkr by some reason):
http://plnkr.co/edit/OACzZbDHyNNNYM9oG5gB?p=preview

Unfortunately their source code looks much cleaner and smaller than my Angular's version of it...

I have implemented it creating a custom directive 
`<art-mailbox></art-mailbox>`

Now I want to change a default behavior by displaying email message not on the same page beneath messages list but on the separate page.

Basically I want to add a routing for right part of my widget, something like this:

```
function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/mailboxes/:mailboxId/:messageId', {
            templateUrl: 'messageView.html',
            controller: 'MessageCtrl'
        })
        .when('/mailboxes/:mailboxId', {
            templateUrl: 'messagesListView.html',
            controller: 'MessagesListCtrl'
        })
```

But the problem is - I don't want to change a page URL.
I want it to stay "http://localhost/index.html" and not "http://localhost/index.html#/mailboxes/inbox/53" because on the same page I will have multiple widgets and I don't want them to disappear after page refresh.

I think I could achieve view switching via `ng-switch` directive but I don't like this approach because i won't have an ability to have custom controllers for each view.

It's kinda ugly. Have a look yourself:

```
<section class="main">
    <div ng-switch="vm.activeMailboxId">
        <div ng-switch-when="none">
            <div ng-include="'partials/mailbox.default.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
            <div ng-include="'partials/mailbox.details.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Picture 1: Green box - widget #1, red box - widget #2.
No emails were selected yet**
[image: Inactive mailbox]
**Picture 2: First email is selected and its content is displayed below**
[image: Active mailbox with 1st message selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show the change on the URL *(but i don't think that there is any possible reason for not to)*.

You have no choise but to use directives, i think `ng-switch` isn't a bad approach, but other possible implementation is to implement a [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive and bind the `templateUrl` to that directiven when you need it.

Could be something like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="selectTemplate(value)'>Inbox 2</a>
//or
<a href="#" ng-click="currentTemplate='inbox2.html'>Inbox 2</a>

<div class="">
  <div ng-include="currentTemplate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I just understand that nothing stops me from assigning a different ng-controller directive to each of my subviews :)